# I'm coding Conway's game of life in python, and my code so far is this:

Tags: python, arrays

```
def initial_board(row, col, array):

    firstList = [[0] * col for i in range(row)]
    for i in firstList:
        i.append(-1)
        i.insert(0,-1)
    firstList.insert(0, [-1] * (col + 2))
    firstList.append([-1] * (col + 2))

    while True:
        coordinateInput = input('Enter the coordinates of a seed cell as \"r c\": ')
        if coordinateInput == '':
            break
        point = coordinateInput.split(' ', 1)
        row = int(point[0])
        col = int(point[1])
        firstList[row][col] = 1

    return firstList

def next_board(row, col, current, new):

    for i in range(1, row - 1):
        for j in range(1, col - 1):
            new[i][j] = live_conditions(i, j, current)

def live_conditions(x, y, array):

    cellCount = 0
    for j in range(y - 1, y + 1):
        for i in range(x - 1, x + 1):
            if not(i == x and j == y):
                if array[i][j] != -1:
                    cellCount += array[i][j]
    if array[x][y] == 1 and cellCount < 2:
        return 0
    if array[x][y] == 1 and cellCount > 3:
        return 0
    if array[x][y] == 0 and cellCount == 3:
        return 1
    else:
        return array[x][y]

def print_board(row, col, array):

    for i in range(row + 2):
        for j in range(col + 2):
            if array[i][j] == 1:
                print('*', end =' ')
            else:
                print(' ', end =' ')
        print()

def game_board():

    while True:
        try:
            row = int(input('What size board? '))
            if row > 0:
                col = row
                break
            else:
                continue
        except ValueError or dimension <= 0:
            pass
    firstList = []
    nextlist = []
    firstList = initial_board(row, col, firstList)
    nextList = [row[:] for row in firstList]

    print()

    generations = int(input('How many generations?: '))
    for gen in range(generations):
        print('Gen: ', gen)
        print_board(row, col, firstList)
        next_board(row, col, firstList, nextList)
        firstList, nextList = nextList, firstList

game_board()
```

However, when I run it, with input of 5 5 I get this:

```
What size board? 5
Enter the coordinates of a seed cell as "r c": 5 5
Enter the coordinates of a seed cell as "r c": 

How many generations?: 3
Gen:  0





          *   

Gen:  1





          *   

Gen:  2





          *
```

I feel like the problem is in my function live_conditions, with cellCount not working properly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the code is not copiling.

Comment: Pasting your entire codebase is not welcome here -- code samples should be the minimum needed to reproduce your immediate problem; if you haven't *identified* your immediate problem, you aren't yet ready to ask a question on StackOverflow. See also http://sscce.org/ and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is your problem, or anyway one problem:

```
for j in range(y - 1, y + 1):
```

As you've written the range, it's iterating over the list [y-1, y], rather than [y-1, y, y+1] as you presumably intended. From the docs:

> the last element is the largest start + i * step less than stop

It's hard to see, however, how this error causes the exact problem you're seeing; it should still count zero neighbours for the single living cell, and snuff it out. I will make my generic suggestion: Add a bunch of print statements and see what the code is doing when it runs.

Edit to add: Actually you've got a similar problem in next_board - you're only updating the range [0, row-1]. So the lower-right corner is never updated. Suggest you check every call to range for off-by-one errors.